# how can I get variable from another function

Tags: function, dart, variables

I imported the main function from another dart file but how can I get the variables inside the main function.

````
import "dartbegin/test.dart" as testt;
// Import the test package

void main() {
  // Define the test
  int l = testt.main().a;
  print(l);
}```

this is test.dart file
````

void main() {
int a = 5;
}```

Comment: can you send us about what have you do to solve it?

Comment: You cannot.  Local variables are local to the function.  Values that you want to pass into the function usually should be supplied as arguments, and values that you want to get from the function usually would need to be returned.